# how to improve the code for checking the emptiness of the array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

When the array is empty "id" of object must be = 1, then the  object  adding to the array, and if the array is not empty, then the object was added and the existing id was + 1. How to improve this code?

**Method of adding:**

```
    addPost(title: string, url: string): void {
    if (this.collection.length == 0) {
        const post:Picture = {
            title,
            url,
            id: 1
        };
        this.collection.unshift(post);
    } else {
        const post:Picture = {
            title,
            url,
            id: this.collection[this.collection.length - 1].id + 1
        };
        this.collection.unshift(post);
    }
}
```

**Array:**

```
export const myCollection: Picture[] = [
{
    id: 1,
    title: "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
    url: "https://placekitten.com/200/198",
}];
```

Comment: Get rid of `id`, since it's basically redundant with the array index…?!

Comment: Or at least, `id: this.collection.length + 1`?

Comment: @deceze Could be that posts can be removed (eg, add first -> id 0, add second -> id 1, remove first, add another -> id 2

Comment: id to delete an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const id = (this.collection.length && this.collection[this.collection.length - 1].id) + 1;
const post: Picture = { title, url, id };
this.collection.unshift(post);
```

If `length` is `0` it becomes `0 + 1`, otherwise it becomes the last `id` `+ 1`.

Comment: The whole logic for getting `id` can further be split off into a separate function for convenience, so you just do `const id = getNextId()`

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the conditional operator to figure out the `id` ahead of time, allowing you to create the declare the `post` and `unshift` just once in the code:

```
addPost(title: string, url: string): void {
  const id: number = this.collection.length
    ? this.collection[this.collection.length - 1].id + 1
    : 0
  const post:Picture = {
    title,
    url,
    id
  };
  this.collection.unshift(post);
}
```